# How to make toolbar icons work like a tab?

Tags: qt, tabs, pyqt, toolbar

I'm very new. Suppose I have a toolbar with 2 buttons: Foo and Bar. Is there a way to make each triggering a different "frame"? That is, the toolbar icons work like tabs. Should each trigger a new window by an on-click event?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [QStackedWidget](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html#details). It provides a way to have multiple widgets on each other where only one is displayed at a time (Like a `QTabWidget`). Here is an example :

```
self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self)
self.stackedWidget.addWidget(firstPageWidget)
self.stackedWidget.addWidget(secondPageWidget)

self.ayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
layout.addWidget(stackedWidget)
setLayout(layout)
```

Now on each button click you can change the current page using `setCurrentIndex`.